# Xamarin.Forms MemoryStream Manipulation. Why is Android different from iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, memorystream, signaturepad

So am using the SignaturePad.PCL nuget package and you can recover a Stream from the plugin that takes the Draw Points and creates an image. Then I am passing that image across to a web service as a base 64 string and displaying it in a web app. Well I found that I was able to get the conversion to base 64 string working like this

```
//This works on android but not iOS
string base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(((MemoryStream) theStream).ToArray());


//Works on iOS but not android
string base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(StreamConvert(theStream));
private byte[] StreamConvert(Stream stream){
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }​
     }


//For both I use this, unless someone else can figure out a cross platform solution
string base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android ? ((MemoryStream) theStream).ToArray() : StreamConvert(theStream));
```

Anyone know why there is a difference?

Comment: From this example it is System.IO.Stream.

Comment: You dind't understand. I want to know types of ´theStream´ in android and ´theStream´ in ios before you convert them to System.IO.Stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a quick look at the SignaturePad's source code ([found here](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/tree/master/src)) and reviewed how the Android and iOS version handle the image it creates.

The main difference is that on Android you get a `Bitmap` object and on iOS you get an `UIImage` object from the SignaturePad's `GetImage()` method. See [here for Android GetImage](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/blob/master/src/SignaturePad.Android/SignaturePadView.cs#L365) and [here for iOS GetImage()](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/blob/master/src/SignaturePad.iOS/SignaturePadView.cs#L305).

**iOS**

Let's drill down into `UIImage` first ([see UIImage here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIImage/)).

Taking a look at how `UIImage` generates it image, you'll find there are several methods that will return an `NSData` object: `ToJPEG()` and `ToPNG()`.

Taking a look at `NSData` [API reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSData/), it has a `ToStream()` method which returns a `Stream` object.

**Android**

Okay, now onto Android!

I found the `Bitmap` [API docs here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Bitmap/). You either get a another `Bitmap` (from the CreateBitmap methods), a `Buffer` (from the CopyBuffer methods) or `Compress` / `CompressAsync`.

[Compress](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Compress/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap+CompressFormat/System.Int32/System.IO.Stream/) and [CompressAsync](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressAsync/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap+CompressFormat/System.Int32/System.IO.Stream/) let you pass in a writeable stream object like `MemoryStream` as the 3rd parameter. Here's an example (from jzeferino's comment):

`var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(); imageBitpmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);`

Hopefully this helps clarify what SignaturePad is doing when it gives you an image.

Comment: ON android you can get the stream with `var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                imageBitpmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);` update your answer.

Comment: This is incredibly insightful. Thank you Lance.